# Osmnx: get the location by gps coordinate

Tags: osmnx

I'm new to the Osmnx, is there any function allows me to get the name of province and city by the GPS coordinates(latitude, longitude) ?

Comment: Are you asking if it has a reverse-geocoder function?

Comment: kinda like: reverse-geocoder(lat, lon) -> "city, province, nation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specifically but you can interact with OSM's Nominatim API's reverse endpoint using OSMnx's [nominatim_request](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.downloader.nominatim_request) function.